# I've bought a car since last year; I've learnt to swim since 2017

Tags: present-perfect

Are the two sentences correct?

> 1. I've learnt to swim since 2017.
> 2. I've bought a car since last year.

Context for 1:

> I moved to this city in 2017. 2017 was a turning point in my life. Before 2017, my life was a mess. Since 2017, my life has changed a lot. I've married a pretty woman. I've found a decent work. I've made lots of friends. I've also learnt to swim since 2017. Before 2017, I tried several times to learn it, but eventually gave up because I was in a bad mood.

Context for 2:

> A: Did we meet last year?
>
> B: Yes, we did.
>
> A: Are you still riding your motorcycle to work?
>
> B: No. I've bought a car since last year.

Comment: Did you check how to use the word "since"?

Comment: A couple of tips: Don't post the same question repeatedly. If you find answers helpful, you should upvote them and/or accept them. Please see https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers  If you are still not clear on your question and you want some things clarified you can leave a comment under an answer, but do not ask the same question again in a different post.

Answer (score 1):

What they mean is:

"Some (unspecified) time after the beginning of 2017 I learned to swim."

"Some (unspecified) time after the start of last year, I bought a car."

- A: "Did we meet last year?"
- B: "Yes we did."
- A: "Have we met since last year?"
- B: "Yes we did, we met last month, don't you remember?"

On the other hand, this sounds unnatural:

- A: Are you still riding your motorcycle to work?
- B: No. I've bought a car since last year.

I would write it as "No. Since last year, I bought a car."

In this context, though, the usage suggests that there was a specific incident that prompted B. to have bought a car, for example: "Since (that time when I had that crash) last year, I bought a car.

Note it should be "I bought" not "I've bought". I find it difficult to explain why.

Comment: aren't both "I bought" and "I've bought" valid and idiomatic?

Comment: @LaurentS Not interchangeably. "I bought" suggests it was an action that took place at a specific time. "I bought a car last year.""I have bought" does not associate with the idea of any particular time, but has the nuance of it being for a purpose: "I have bought a car, as I was required to do", or "I have bought the tickets for tomorrow's concert" (compare "I bought the tickets yesterday").

Comment: @LaurentS. In any case, the usage of "I have (verb)" at the same time specifying *when* this was done does not feel right. "I have washed the dishes this morning" should either be "I washed the dishes this morning" or "I have washed the dishes -- I did it this morning."

Comment: Thanks for explanation :-) French native here, so I have the tendency to use it wrong when doing too litteral translation.

Answer (score 1):

> *I moved to this city in 2017. And 2017 was the turning point in my life, **my life has changed a lot since then**;*

Here the **Present Perfect** is used correctly because the speaker's life is ongoing, other new and positive changes might occur further on in his or her life. The present perfect is also used to describe a state or event which began in the past and continues to the present time.

> ***I got*** *married*, **found** *a decent job,*  ***made*** *lots of friends,* ***bought*** *a new car but  I also **learnt*** ***how*** *to swim. Before 2017, I **tried*** *learning it several times  but I always **gave up*** *because I **felt** unsatisfied.*

Here I would use the **Simple Past** because the speaker *knows* **when** they got married, found a better job, made new friends etc. The time of these events is fixed  in the speaker's mind. Although the reader knows the marriage must have taken place sometime between 2017 and 2020, they might infer that it happened before 2020 seeing as we are in the month of June and the COVID pandemic exploded between February and March of this year. It's unlikely that any of the above events happened *after* January 2020.

According to *Advanced Grammar in Use* by Martin Hewings, first published in 1999, the adverb “since” is normally used in the present perfect but it can also be used with the simple past if it is embedded in a clause and  the main clause is in the Present Perfect.

> In a sentence which includes a *since*-clause , the usual pattern is for the *since*-clause to contain a past simple, and the main clause to contain a present perfect:

- *Since* Mr Hassan **became** president, both taxes and unemployment **have increased**.
- I **haven't been able** to play tennis *since* I **broke** my arm.

> However, we can use a present perfect in the *since*-clause if the two situations described in the main and *since*-clause extend until the present:
>
> - *Since* **I've lived** here, I **haven't seen** my neighbours.

The teacher of English writing for the BBC site, *[Learning English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv299.shtml)*, elucidates

> The tense in the **since-clause** can be **past** or **perfect**, depending on whether it refers to a **point in the past** or to a **period of time** leading up to the present or, in the case of the past perfect, leading up to a point in the past. […] Note also in these examples that **present** and **past** tenses are possible in the **main** clause as well as the **present perfect**:

- Henry’s been teetotal since we **got** married.
  Henry’s been teetotal since **we’ve been** married.
- It’s only a week since I **met** him, but we’re very much in love.
  It’s only a week since **we’ve known** each other, but we’re very much in love.
- They’re a lot happier since they **separated**.
  They’re a lot happier since **they’ve been living** apart.
- You’re looking much better since you **came out** of hospital.
  You’re looking much better since **you’ve been out** of hospital.

Comment: but made a new friends does not correspond to a fixed date more on a period that can extend up to now so present perfect can be fine

Comment: It says **since 2017**, so the act of meeting and making friends happened between 2017 and the very recent past. It is the speaker who *knows* when these friends were made. If the time is not specified then PP is usually the preferred option, e.g. She's had three parking fines this year. "This year" is an unfinished period of time

Answer (score 0):

Both your examples are unusual. Neither is idiomatic. That's to say that you are not likely to hear native English speakers using them.

While you might well hear **I've have been swimming regularly since 2017**, you are unlikely to hear **I have learned to swim since 2017**.

Far more likely is either the omission of **since 2017** or use of the simple past as in **I learned to swim a few years ago**.

Alternatively, **I have been learning to swim since 2017** (grammatical but unlikely).

The same applies to buying the car. The likely options are:

> No, I've have bought a car.
>   No, I've since bought a car.
>   No, I've bought a car since then.
>   No, I bought a car (a few months ago)
>   No, I've been driving a car since the end of last year.

**Since** is more likely to be followed by a continuing activity than a single action - with lots of exceptions.

There are numerous guides online to the use of since. Google **use of since** and/or see:
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/since
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/since
https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/since

Comment: "I have been learning to swim since 2017" - this implies that you started learning to swim three years ago (at present) and have not yet learned.